# What happens to a disputed flag?

Tags: support, flags

I came here to know why my flag was marked as Disputed flag, I read various other posts explaining wat is Disputed flag and I got understood what it is. But I am still not sure *what happens to a Disputed flag?* **Can it change to a Helpful/Declined flag in future?** (say based on number of Moderators vote for it or something like that)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nothing happens to it after it is marked disputed, because that means it was dismissed.

More specifically, a normal user disputed it and it was later dismissed, either manually by an actual moderator or automatically by an event (i.e., post deletion). If you flag something as very low quality, an edit by anyone will dispute that flag as well.

Unless the developers mess around with the database, it will not change, ever. Moderators can't override normal users in this regard — if someone marks a flag as invalid, it will always end up disputed, even if a moderator explicitly marks it helpful later on.

Comment: So I can again go and flag it or what if someone flags it and it gets approved?

Comment: Can you point me to some link explainin how a normal user can dispute a flag?

Comment: @akjoshi 10k users get an [additional "invalid flag" option](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/flag/135813?showInvalid=true) when flagging from the flag queue.

Comment: @akjoshi - edits to posts you flag as very low quality cause them to be disputed. I'm not sure if that's edits from all users or just edits from 10k users though.

Comment: @awoodland Oh, I forgot about that. AFAIK it's edits by everyone. I had VLQ flags marked disputed at the same time as an edit by the 1-rep owner.

Comment: Thanks @awoodland, lunboks : What about answers from user's not having privilege to post comments? and answers having comments? will the flags on them be disputed?

Comment: If I have flagged an answer, then the answer is deleted, likely because I flagged it, then why should that become disputed?

Answer (score 7):

The status of a disputed flag is definitive, if (as lunboks said) developers don't alter the content of the database. Moderators don't vote on it; they can dismiss it as not useful, but the status of the flag is still *disputed*.

A flag is marked as disputed when a 10K user, who can see the post flags (but not who flagged the post) selected "invalid flag" in a dialog similar to the following one. (The screenshot has been taken on *English Language & Usage*.)

[image: screenshot]

10K users don't see the comment flags, and post flags for which a custom reason has been entered.