# Should we raise flags for obviously garbage questions so they will be deleted by moderator?

Tags: discussion, flags, etiquette

Users in [10000, <s>15000</s> 20000) reputation range have to wait *2 days* before they can nominate question for deletion, but at the same time FAQ says

[image]

Today I've used this option and flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362092/the-share-button) -- it obviously offtopic, has nothing in common with programming and doesn't bring anything useful to Stack Overflow, thus IMO we should immediately burn it with fire.

But a moderator declined my flag:

[image]

I know I can wait for two days and then vote to delete, but it very likely that I will forget to come back.

Who was right and what should we do with such *garbage* questions?

Comment: Range is actually `[10000, 20000)`, not `[10000, 15000)`.

Comment: Won't that question get auto-deleted in the next cleanup cycle based on the score and OP's rep?

Comment: Surely the flag description could have been a bit more descriptive than that.

Comment: That seems like enough info for a flag description.

Comment: @Rachel According [to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/148672) the OP's rep wouldn't come into it. Is this answer out of date or incomplete?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter That's probably correct then. I'm probably mixing up the script that auto-deletes posts with the one that auto-deletes users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a dedicated flag message for that. It's called "very low quality":

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

But the question you link to is barely an hour old. That's not even *one* day, that's like, 1/24th of it. Your flag was probably declined because chances are it would have been taken care of within the day by other users with higher privileges (20k+ users can vote to delete questions immediately, and we have far more of them than moderators) and as such it didn't **need** moderator intervention just yet. We have a lot of flags to deal with as it is, and if the community can already handle this for us, it's better to leave it to the community so we can focus on more pressing issues.

But whatever, I deleted it.

Comment: I don't know, I've seen some atrocious questions (I'll have to search through my history) where I've flagged them as "very low quality" and had the flag rejected with a similar message, or the exact same message.  I've stopped flagging as low quality, and just waiting the two days.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: That was just to say he didn't need to waste time typing out a custom message because there's already an option designed for this.

Comment: Doesn't the `Very Low Quality` flag get marked disputed if any edit to the post is made ? (And in the case of new questions, the chances of an edit being made are pretty high which kind of makes the flag redundant)

Comment: @AshRj: Really? I thought the disputed mark only comes if a 10k user marks as invalid..

Comment: @Manishearth http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149059/should-minor-edits-by-the-op-cause-very-low-quality-flags-to-be-disputed

Comment: @Manishearth: Yes, it's disputed by the user editing the post as a way of saying "hey, this *is* salvageable, let me prove it with an edit". Of course, AshRj makes a good point - just because you edit something doesn't always mean it's going to help matters any.

Comment: Asking out of curiosity, is there any data available on flags, specifically, the Low Quality Flag (Number of flags, Accepted flags, Rejected Flags, Disputed Flags) ? The Data-Explorer doesnt seem to have this data.